# Silverlight/RIA Services and ASP .NET MVC/WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, asp.net-web-api, wcf-ria-services

[I did some research around but I have some doubts still about following topic](http://www.wintellect.com/download/index/silverlightmigration)...

I have **Silverlight/RIA Services** project that needs to have **ASP.NET MVC look as well as WebAPI** for some different clients.

So my question is following

> Can we use somehow RIA Services with ASP.NET MVC 5?
>
> And if not what is a painless way to represent all existing logic in ASP.NET MVC?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "needs to have ASP.NET MVC look"? Also, I take it that the WebAPI requirement really is a REST API requirement? Surely your clients don't care what server-side frameworks you use?

Comment: @John Silverlight and RIA Services are dead. I need to migrate project to something new but if there is a change to use RIA Services  + ASP.NET MVC is much painless than migrate entire project.

Comment: Silverlight is dead, but RIA Services can, in principle, be still used as it's gone open source (open ria services). That can be an option primarily if you migrate the client to a proper .NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ria services have nothing to do with look and feel.

A Silverlight app or a non plugin, which uses RIA services can be hosted in a web page created using ASP.Net.

---

> Can we use somehow RIA Services with ASP.NET MVC 5?

Yes.

RIA services which could be used by an asp.net backend would not gain the benefit of RIA services because changes made in the backend end are not *generated forward* to an application such as a Silverlight plugin. It just becomes another way of accessing data.

Comment: Would you mind to clarify about the cost of re-usage RIA Services in ASP.NET MVC or generateing WebAPI Business Logic from scratch grabbing some stuff of RIA Services code?  I mean the code of RIA Services I have is a big one and have lots fo logic to work with EF. So i need to know which is painless approach I have to use,

Comment: @Dimi If code re-use is paramount, there is no reason why the existing services cannot be used and it sounds like you answered your own question. I believe that the real question is how much code debt in older/unused technology should be leveraged going forward? It will be harder to find developers to work on RIA systems, whereas EF is more universally used.